# Using jQuery .load() - Not working

Tags: jquery

```
$("#link1").click(function(){
$("#div1").load('../test.html');
return false;
});
```

This is an incredibly simple .load() function that simply does not seem to be working. Website has a 'js' folder where this code is being called in 'my-scripts.js' (within a doc ready function), test.html is located one directory up from the js folder (the main website folder) yet clicking the anchor with the 'link1' id does nothing.

**EDIT**: I've tried taking out the '../' too, and still nothing.

**EDIT**: This is a local website using WAMP - It's a Wordpress theme I'm making, too if that helps.

**FINAL EDIT**: Turns out since test.html wasn't in the root directory (outside of the wordpress theme folder) it wasn't finding it... strange since everyone suggested it should be in the same location as the calling html/php file. Thanks everyone.

Apologies in advance for possible lack of information as it's my first post.

What could be the cause? Is the mark up correct?
Thanks.

Comment: The `../` will be relative to the current document, not the js file.

Comment: Thanks forgot to mention I've already tried that - See edit.

Comment: stupid question, but do you actually have an element with the id "#div1" in your document? Also, have you checked the path of the URL parameter? It should be relative to the document, not relative to the script file.

Comment: @Mushii Then use a tool like Firebug's "net" tab to see what the request returns. You are not on a `file://` url with this, correct?

Comment: Following what Pekka said, always use some browser based resource monitor to inspect what your browser is requesting, so you can spot 404s and identify these sort of problems quickly.  For instance, [Firebug's Net panel](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/fa940bfc37.png).

Comment: Check with the developer tools of your browser, whether the request is initiated and what is the response.

Comment: Yes, the element and ID is there and yes the path to the URL is correct (when not using the '../') the file exists.

Comment: Edits made - I'm running local. I'll check with a debugger.

Comment: Just to make sure your selector is correct, if you substitute your `$("#div1").load(..)` call with a simple `alert('got here');`, do you get the alert?  Probably overly obvious, but it doesn't hurt to make sure you're actually able to get your click event to fire.

Comment: Hey David, yeah I did an alert which showed up curiously in Chrome but not FF. So it should all be in order, very strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird question, since it seems to have been resolved completely in the comments.

> FINAL EDIT: Turns out since test.html wasn't in the root directory (outside of the wordpress theme folder) it wasn't finding it... strange since everyone suggested it should be in the same location as the calling html/php file. Thanks everyone.

Assuming a document root (ie. the base WordPress directory) of:

```
/var/www
```

And a theme directory of:

```
/var/www/wp-content/themes/my-theme
```

And a theme template file of:

```
/var/www/wp-content/themes/my-theme/js/my-scripts.js
```

If you want to display `/var/www/wp-content/themes/my-theme/test.html`, you need to construct the `.load()` URL in relation to the page being displayed; the actual file on disk is irrelevant (i.e. don't construct the path relative to my-scripts.js). You would probably want to use the absolute path:

```
$('#div1').load('/wp-content/themes/my-theme/test.html');
```

Comment: Legend. That's exactly what I needed. Only it required './' at the beginning of the absolute path in order for it to work. Thanks a lot, Adam.